# How to tell how many bytes were actually written FileOutputStream.write after it throws IOException?

Tags: java

For example if I run out of disk space, or there's some other kind of filesystem error, can I somehow inspect the `IOException` thrown by `FileOutputStream.write(byte[])` and tell how many bytes were actually written before the error?

Comment: Look at the results. Are you writing to a file? How much data was actually written to the file? As for keeping track of the buffer, it's not exposed, so I doubt you could. Would be nice to know what you are trying to do, so we could better help you achieve what you need. This could be an XY problem for all we know.

Comment: Can you just check the size of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Not from `FileOutputStream` directly. You'll need a wrapper stream around it that does the counting, such as Apache's [CountingOutputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/output/CountingOutputStream.html).